# How to ask "sbt-idea" plugin not download the sources of plugins when running `gen-idea sbt-classifiers`?

Tags: plugins, download, sbt

With the help of [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea), I can generate files for Intellij-idea.

And using this commands, I can download the source-jar and doc-jar for all the dependencies:

```
gen-idea sbt-classifiers
```

But it will try to download the source-jar for the plugins also. Sometimes when I use a global **snapshot** sbt plugin, like:

```
"com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.7.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Sbt will try to download the source of it even I don't need it in current project. The problem is it very slow to download it, often spend more than 30 seconds in my country, so I want it not to be downloaded.

Is there any way to let sbt not download the source-jar files of sbt plugins, or the one I specify here?

Answer (score 1):

run this in sbt:

gen-idea no-classifiers